# How to save and get CSV file attachment from Email in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv, email-attachments

I am having some data storing in Core Data. I successfully export the core data records into CSV file and send that CSV file to end user as attachment.

I am to know iPhone does not allow to save the attachments other than image. Rather it gives some options to view the attachment like pdf.

But I want to save the CSV file that is attached through mail in iCloud/alternative and I able to get the path of CSV file saved.To save that records to core data again even user deleted all the core data records after exporting them & clicked import option.

Till now I have done exporting the CSV file and sending mail. Also I have done saving the CSV file in documents directory and parsing the CSV file and saving to core data again..

Below is my code..using Documents Directory.

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate;

 appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSManagedObjectContext *context=[appDelegate managedObjectContext];
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@“sample.csv"];
if (filePath) {
        NSString * myText = [[NSString alloc]
                             initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                             encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                             error:nil];
        if (myText) {
            __block int count = 0;

            [myText enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString * line, BOOL * stop) {
                line=[line stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@" "];
                NSArray *lineComponents=[line componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
                if(lineComponents){

                     float f=[[lineComponents objectAtIndex:0] floatValue];
                     NSNumber *number=[NSNumber numberWithFloat:f];
                     NSString *string1=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:1];
                     NSString *string2=[lineComponents objectAtIndex:2];
                     NSManagedObject *object=[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@“Record” inManagedObjectContext:context];
                     [object setValue:number forKey:@"number"];
                     [object setValue:string1 forKey:@"string1"];
                     [object setValue:string2 forKey:@"string2"];
                     NSError *error;
                     count++;
                     if(count>=1000){
                     if (![context save:&error]) {
                     NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                     }
                     count=0;

                     }
                }
            }];
            NSLog(@"done importing");
            NSError *error;
            if (![context save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }
            else
            {
                [[[UIAlertView alloc]  initWithTitle:@"CSV" message:@"File Imported successfully" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
            }

        }
    }
```

Any ideas how to save the CSV attachment..will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693305/attach-csv-to-email-xcode

Comment: I have done all the stuff..Mailing the CSV file..as done in above link..I need to save the attachment in iCloud or any other file manager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully done saving CSV file into iCloud using below link

[Save iOS 8 Documents to iCloud Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051437/save-ios-8-documents-to-icloud-drive)

I have used below link for retrieving the iCloud Files/Documents.

https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync

Export/Import Documents can be referred using below link

[Export & Import Documents using iCloud in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293305/export-import-documents-using-icloud-in-ios)