# Export & Import Documents using iCloud in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, icloud-drive

I am developing an app that makes user to export core data records into an document using iCloud Drive/iCloud Documents/iCloud Kit and he can able to import and access those document at another device.

I mean Export/Import of documents within devices that are using same application. Documents can be identified by unique document name for importing..

Please Give any suggestions for above task. Which one is more useful..or suggest any other useful links for above task.

1) **iCloud Documents.** (Documents Storage)

2) **iCloud Kit.**(Huge/complex amount of data)

3) **Key-Value Storage.**(Small amount of data)

I have successfully implemented export/import using iCloud Documents. But I am able to access the documents which are exported in same device only. As it stores with local storage..

I used iCloudSync for retrieving the documents.

https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync

Now, I am referring iCloud Kit for accessing within same app & multiple devices..

Thanks..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully accessed the iCloud Files with same iCloud Account within multiple devices using below code

```
NSArray *tempArray=[[iCloud sharedCloud] listCloudFiles];
```

**Source**: https://github.com/iRareMedia/iCloudDocumentSync

It will retrieve all the iCloud files of same logged in iCloud Account that are exported from various devices..