# How do i exactly export a csv file from iOS written in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, csv, export

I am trying to export an cvs file.

With the following code i manage to get the file

```
let fileName = "sample.csv"//"sample.txt"        
    @IBAction func createFile(sender: AnyObject) {
            let path = tmpDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
            let contentsOfFile = "No,President Name,Wikipedia URL,Took office,Left office,Party,Home State\n1,George Washington,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington,30/04/1789,4/03/1797,Independent,Virginia\n2,John Adams,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Adams,4/03/1797,4/03/1801,Federalist,Massachusetts\n3,Thomas Jefferson,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Jefferson,4/03/1801,4/03/1809,Democratic-Republican,Virginia\n4,James Madison,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Madison,4/03/1809,4/03/1817,Democratic-Republican,Virginia\n5,James Monroe,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Monroe,4/03/1817,4/03/1825,Democratic-Republican,Virginia\n6,John Quincy Adams,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Quincy_Adams,4/03/1825,4/03/1829,Democratic-Republican/National Republican,Massachusetts"
                //"Sample Text repacement for future cvs data"content to save

            // Write File

            do {
                try contentsOfFile.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("File sample.txt created at tmp directory")
            } catch {

                print("Failed to create file")
                print("\(error)")
            }

        }

// Share button
    @IBAction func shareDoc(sender: AnyObject) {
        print("test share file")

         docController.UTI = "public.comma-separated-values-text"
            docController.delegate = self//delegate
            docController.name = "Export Data"
            docController.presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem(sender as! UIBarButtonItem, animated: true)

        //}
    }
```

When i click the share file button in the simulator i see the following:

[image]

and with quick look it shows

[image]

So the next thing i did was testing with my iphone 5 and i tried to email sample.csv but i am only getting the message body and not the csv file???

1. how can i actually email the .csv file?
2. which export possibilities are there?

Answer (score 22):

In order to email the .csv file, you can do the following:

1. Add this import to the top of the class. It allows you to use MFMailComposeViewController, which is a way to send emails.

   ```
   import MessageUI
   ```
2. Generate your data, a sample I have done is:

   ```
   // Creating a string.
   var mailString = NSMutableString()
   mailString.appendString("Column A, Column B\n")
   mailString.appendString("Row 1 Column A, Row 1 Column B\n")
   mailString.appendString("Row 2 Column A, Row 2 Column B\n")

   // Converting it to NSData.
   let data = mailString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

   // Unwrapping the optional.
   if let content = data {           
       print("NSData: \(content)")
   }
   ```
3. Generate the MFMailComposeViewController

   ```
   // Generating the email controller.
       func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
           let emailController = MFMailComposeViewController()
           emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self
           emailController.setSubject("CSV File")
           emailController.setMessageBody("", isHTML: false)

           // Attaching the .CSV file to the email.
           emailController.addAttachmentData(data!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "Sample.csv")

           return emailController
       }

   // If the view controller can send the email.
   // This will show an email-style popup that allows you to enter
   // Who to send the email to, the subject, the cc's and the message.
   // As the .CSV is already attached, you can simply add an email 
   // and press send.
       let emailViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()
       if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
           self.presentViewController(emailViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }
   ```

In your case, as you have already created the file, you can simply attach that directly by changing the line where the CSV is attached to the mail for:

```
    emailController.addAttachmentData(NSData(contentsOfFile: "YourFile")!, mimeType: "text/csv", fileName: "Sample.csv")
```

Answer based on: [Attach csv to email xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24693305/attach-csv-to-email-xcode) ,
[Create CSV file in Swift and write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33349139/create-csv-file-in-swift-and-write-to-file)

Answer (score 18):

> Creating CSV file in Swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var taskArr = [Task]()
var task: Task!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    task = Task()
    for _ in 0..<5 {
        task.name = "Raj"
        task.date = "\(Date())"
        task.startTime = "Start \(Date())"
        task.endTime = "End \(Date())"
        taskArr.append(task!)
    }

    creatCSV()
}

// MARK: CSV file creating
    func creatCSV() -> Void {
        let fileName = "Tasks.csv"
        let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        var csvText = "Date,Task Name,Time Started,Time Ended\n"

        for task in taskArr {
            let newLine = "\(task.date),\(task.name),\(task.startTime),\(task.endTime)\n"
            csvText.append(newLine)
        }

        do {
            try csvText.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to create file")
            print("\(error)")
        }
        print(path ?? "not found")
    }
}
```

> Task Model class

```
class Task: NSObject {
    var date: String = ""
    var name: String = ""
    var startTime: String = ""
    var endTime: String = ""
}
```

> CSV output show as below format

[image]

Comment: can set a text to align center?

Comment: I didn't find any solution regarding text alignment for csv file.

Comment: How we can do it In swift 4?

Comment: Hello @Antony, This code is working with Swift 4 also

Comment: But WhatsApp throwing message that the item cannot be shared select different item

Comment: Where can I get acces to this file?

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 5**

```
func creatCSV() {
    let fileName = "exportar_serv.csv"

    /* CREAR UN ARCHIVO NUEVO EN EL DIRECTORIO PRINCIPAL */
    guard let path = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName) as NSURL else {
        return }

    var csvText = "id,name,imageName\n"

    for task in taskArr {
        let x : Int64 = task.id!
        let id2 = String(x)

        let newLine = "\(id2),\(task.name),\(task.imageName)\n"
        csvText.append(newLine)
    } // for

    do {
        try csvText.write(to: path as URL, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("DATOS GUARDADOS")
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    } // catch

} // CreateCSV
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5.0.1, Xcode 10.2.1 version

```
    private func injectExportButton() {
    var csvIcon: UIImage
    switch self.theme {
    case .dark:
        csvIcon = UIImage(named: "csv-export.dark", in: Bundle.framework)!
    case .light:
        csvIcon = UIImage(named: "csv-export.light", in: Bundle.framework)!
    }
            let imgWidth = csvIcon.size.width
            let imgHeight = csvIcon.size.height
            let button: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgWidth, height: imgHeight))
            button.setBackgroundImage(csvIcon, for: UIControl.State())
            button.alpha = 0
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(csvExportButtonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                button.alpha = 1
            }
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)

}

@objc private func csvExportButtonClicked() {
    debugPrint("export clicked")
    createCSV()
}

private func createCSV() -> Void {
    let fileName = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("OutputD.csv")
    var csvOutputText = "Result, Date, Name\n"
    history.results.forEach { result in
        let newLine = "\(String(describing: result.value)),\(String(describing: result.date)),\(String(describing: result.name))\n"
        csvOutputText.append(newLine)
    }
    do {
        try csvOutputText.write(to: fileName, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to create file")
        print("\(error)")
    }
    let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["your results", fileName], applicationActivities: nil)
    present(activity, animated: true)
}

private func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return paths[0]
}
```

Comment: change history.results for your array of strings. then just put injectExportButton() whenever you need it and that's all - the button will work "out of the box" on any Navigation Controller