# Swift - Export CSV using UIActivityViewController

Tags: swift, csv, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am working on some code to export some data to be opened in another program. The data needs to be formatted as a CSV which then would be shared with the UIActivityViewController. Everything works except that the data type is not CSV. You can save it to files and see the raw data, but the file type is not CSV.

Researching how to do this led me to [this stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32593516/how-do-i-exactly-export-a-csv-file-from-ios-written-in-swift) It mostly follow the code down below, but then puts it into an attachment specifically for an email. I need it to open in the other app that will read the CSV file.

```
let csvString = NSMutableString()
csvString.append("\(String(describing: selectedAirstrip.id!)), \(String(describing: selectedAirstrip.lat!)), \(String(describing: selectedAirstrip.lon!))\n")

// Converting it to NSData
let data = csvString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue, allowLossyConversion: false)

let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data!], applicationActivities: [])
present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered. I appreciate it immensely.

Comment: What is the file type? What is the actual problem?

Comment: FYI - Never use `String(describing:)` for anything other than debugging.

Comment: I basically need to convert the variable data to a csv file

Comment: I understand that. But you must do so without using `String(describing:)`. And you need to clarify your question.